# Run older iOS version XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

There are several related posts here, but solutions provided is not available for now.

I discovered a bug, that is only occur on iOS 7 version. Unfortunately, i don't have device running on that version. I need to add a simulator that run on older version. Is there any way to achieve that? I did not find a solution (only download old XCode, but i hope there is a better way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no other solution than downloading older versions of Xcode.
I needed this a few months ago, and tried a lot of different things, but I didn't found a solution.
Only downloading old Xcode version...

Comment: thats a shame on Apple

Comment: Be really careful when dealing with multiple versions of Xcode. If you run the release installer, it tends to delete your old version. I suggest creating a zip archive of your Xcode 6 once you've installed it, since at some point you'll probably forget and install an Xcode 7 upgrade, and WHAM, goodbye Xcode 6. Recovering is worse than a download because you then need to install the extra components, re download the documentation, etc. It ends up costing you several hours. Very annoying.